# Loop through a LinkedList

Tags: java, multithreading, linked-list

I'm trying to get a `LinkedList` from my buffer class (`BufferCharacter`) and then loop through every element in the `LinkedList` in the `Reader` class. But when I try return the `LinkedList` in the `get()` method in `BufferCharacter` class I then cannot loop through it in the `Reader` class. I've tried to loop through the List in the `Buffer` class and then return each element from there but that doesn't work either.

Any help is highly appreciated!

```
 public class CharacterBuffer {

    private char ch;
    private LinkedList buffer = new LinkedList();
    private boolean filled;

    public void put(char ch) {
        buffer.addLast(ch);
    }

    public void filled() {
        filled = true;
    }

    public Object get() throws InterruptedException {
        while (buffer.isEmpty()) {
            // wait();
            return "Waiting";
        }
        return buffer;
    }

    public synchronized void putSync(char ch) {
        buffer.addLast(ch);
    }

    public synchronized Object getSync() throws InterruptedException {
        while (buffer.isEmpty()) {
            // wait();
            return "---------";
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<buffer.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(buffer.get(i));
        }

        return buffer;

    }

    public int size(){
        return buffer.size();
    }

}

public class Reader extends Thread {

    private GUIMutex gui;
    private CharacterBuffer buffer;
    private boolean isSynced;

    public Reader(GUIMutex gui, CharacterBuffer buffer, boolean isSynced) {
        this.gui = gui;
        this.buffer = buffer;
        this.isSynced = isSynced;
    }

    public void run() {
        String data = "test";
        while (true) {

            try {
                // data = buffer.get();
                if (isSynced) {
                    gui.setReaderText(buffer.getSync() + "\n");
                } else {
                    for(int i = 0; i<buffer.get().size(); i++){
                         gui.setReaderText(i);
                    }
                    gui.setReaderText(buffer.get() + "\n");
                }
                Thread.sleep(700);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at Java's optimised for loop? E.g. for(Object o : buffer) {...}.  Or the list iterator?

Comment: There are more issues with your code.  The get() and getSync() method will not "wait" until the buffer is not empty (it will return "Waiting" and exit the method).  It is better to type your LinkedList, e.g. List<Character> buffer = new LinkedList<>();

Comment: Wrapping every `char` in a `Character` to store in a `List` is a terrible idea. The extra memory allocation and garbage collection will be a silly use of resources. Why not use a `StringBuilder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't understand what you are talking about; so lets try to shed some light here.

In the end, you are talking about some kind of "collection" class that contains multiple elements; in your case a LinkedList. The thing is: in order to make use of such a class, you need a clear understanding of the APIs you intend to provide.

You figured that you want to use that *buffer* to store individual char values, that you add using `putSync()`.

But then ... what exactly is `getSync()` supposed to do?

In your case, you are simply returning the buffer, and that is probably **wrong**.

Instead, you want to have methods like:

```
synchronized boolean hasNext()
```

and

```
synchronized char getNext()
```

A user of your class can call the first method to figure: are there other chars; and if so, the second method returns those values.

That would a first, simple way to improve your code. A more reasonable way would be that you implement a method `getIterator()` that would return an object implementing the [Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) interface.

Other things to note: if you are using the "built-in" [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html); please understand that this class supports generics!

Thus you should be using it like:

```
private final List<Character> buffer = new LinkedList<>();
```

to get all the benefits from using strongly typed collections!

EDIT: upon your comments, I think using a **LinkedList** is simply the wrong approach here.

Instead of using a List, you want to use a [Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html), like:

```
private final Queue<Character> buffer = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
```

That class gives you that functionality that one party can **add** elements at the queue tail; whereas another party **removes** elements from the queue head.

Extra bonus: that class is doing the synchronisation work for you already, so you don't need to care about that!

Comment: How would I exactly return those values? Code example would be easy to understand. Also I very much appreciate your help! The getSync is supposed to just return values, if the list is empty it just returns "waiting". I have 2 threads in this program, one that writes characters to the list and one that reads them

Comment: That is the thing: you haven't explained anywhere what you want to return. Do you intend to return ALL content of that buffer as a single string? And hint: returning a string that says "waiting" is a very bad idea.

Comment: I wan't to return each element, which is in this case each character. I'm using these characters in a thread and printing them in a textArea. https://gyazo.com/6232569cabd31f2fa5a85506e1224d5a is a screenshot of an example how it should run.

Comment: That is the point: **how** do you think you could return MULTIPLE character values using a single call? That is my whole point: you don't have a clear understanding of what your interface is actually supposed to do!

Comment: I'm not using a single call, The thread is doing a call every 0.7 sec, which then should be able to return one character each. I've tried this: ´return buffer.removeFirst():´ which works. But that is not exactly what I wan't. (Sorry if I'm coming off as rude, I have a "rude" way of typing sometime)

Comment: Please see my updated answer; I think you should exchange your List with a Queue - that class allows you exactly to do what it looks like you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use StringBuilder instead

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
  // add chars using sb.append(char)
  for (int i = 0, n = sb.length(); i < n; i++)
  {
     char c = sb.charAt(i);
  }

  or

  String s = sb.toString();
```